# Is there software for stress-testing computer displays?

Tags: display, diagnostic

I am working with a monitor in our offices that appears to have a malfunctioning DVI interface.  When the monitor is in DVI mode, even with cables disconnected, there is serious ghosting, artifacts, bleed over and text fuzzing.

However, HDMI seems to be working fine. I'd like to find a piece of software that would potentially stress the internals of a monitor. Maybe something like a digital snow pattern that iterates through all of the possible colors as rapidly as possible, or something like that? Basically, any software that stresses the monitor components, not necessarily the GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be [Monitor Test](http://www.passmark.com/products/monitortest.htm) from Passmark.

Comment: This was as close as I could find.  I really wanted something that was more of a stress test, but running the test loop at 1 second per display did do a relatively good job of redrawing pixels.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Hiren's version 10.4 you can simply load the disk and run the Windows Command Menu if it does not autorun and then under the heading Testing, there is a Monitor Tester that should do what you need.

Comment: This one is called "IsMyLCDOK" v1.02